# Is it Tate or the Tate, Tate Britatin/Modern or the Tate Britain/Modern?

Tags: articles, definite-article, proper-nouns

This is really confusing, as event on the museum's website, there are different examples, such as in [this](https://www.tate.org.uk/about-us/history-tate) article:

> ...the gallery at Millbank, now known as Tate Britain, was built and
> opened in 1897. (no article)
>
> the Gallery's official title was the National Gallery of British Art,
> although it was referred to as the Tate Gallery. (definite article)
>
> During his 28 years at Tate, his vision led to the creation of Tate
> Modern and the redefinition of the original gallery at Millbank as
> Tate Britain. (no article)

And even here, where the word 'Tate' is used as a noun adjunct:

> The entrance and staircase of the Centenary Development were named after Tate benefactor, Sir Edwin Manton.

These were examples from the museum's website, but in one of recent books on art, I found the following sentence:

> ...art students and faculty walked out of classes and refused to
> attend exhibitions at The Tate, the Reina Sophia, or the MoMA.

[This website](https://usefulenglish.ru/grammar/part-8-articles-with-miscellaneous-proper-names), for example, suggests using the before 'Tate Gallery', but gives no clue about 'Tate', 'Tate Modern' and 'Tate Britain', and different sources seem to have different approaches to this. So... is there any rule? It's really confusing.

Comment: No, there is no rule. It used to be known as 'the Tate Gallery', but when it was divided into 'Tate Modern' and 'Tate Britain' they seem to have dropped the article.